# CreateJS - How to know when an object is added on the stage?

Tags: createjs

I'm using create js to convert flash object into javascript.
I want to use a function in the object's timeline when the stage is created, but this function doesn't exist when i call it.
How to know when the object is fully added on stage ?

```
var button = new lib.objCreateJs();
stage_createJs.addChild(button);
button.move(); // return " Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'move' "
```

part my object :

```
(function (lib, img, cjs) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes

// stage content:
    (lib.objCreateJs = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
        this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{})
        // timeline functions:
        this.frame_0 = function() {
            this.move = function()
            {
                this.mcBouge.gotoAndStop("move");
            }
        }
```

**I got the answer :
the stage must be updated (stage.update(); ) when an object is added.**

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept that answer, so the question will be marked as ’solved’